# Laravel back button

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a simple back button on a page. The user can arrive to this page from two different pages so I would like to know from which page he arrived. Is that possible?

Comment: `{{ url()->previous() }}` in Laravel 5

Answer (score 190, accepted):

In Laravel, you can do something like this: `<a href="{{ Request::referrer() }}">Back</a>` (assuming you're using Blade).

**Laravel 4**

```
{{ URL::previous() }}
```

**Laravel 5+**

```
{{ url()->previous() }}
```

[Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/urls#accessing-the-current-url)

Comment: Thanks this works!! Could not find this in the documentation... is there anywhere else i can get more out of laravel?

Comment: You can check out the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs), use their [forums](http://forums.laravel.com/), browse the source in the laravel folder or hang in their [IRC channel](http://laravel.com/irc) #laravel on freenode.  Highly recommend the IRC channel lots of friendly and helpful people on to answer your questions, day or night.

Comment: I'd recommend you to check out the [API docs](http://laravel.com/api) too, it contains many useful things the documentation doesn't cover. I learn a lot of Laravel and advanced PHP stuffs just by reading the source code and API docs.

Comment: @Anon Why is this throwing me an error? `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::referrer()`

Comment: @yannishristofakis Are you using Laravel 4? The URL behaviour changed, so use `URL::previous()` instead.

Comment: Request::header("referrer");

Comment: the problem with this and the URL::previous() approach is that it is based on the http referrer. 1) This might not be set by all user agents, so you cannot rely on it all the time. 2) Moreover, if it is set but you visit  the specific page from a link on an external source, you would go back to that source.

Comment: @Ramesh Your solution helps in L5. You did mispell 'referer' though, it's with 1 'r'.

Comment: this one works in L5.2 <a href="{{ url()->previous() }}">

Comment: If there is on "Back" to return to then how do you use `{{ url()->previous() }}` so that it does not show when your first enter a web page but only shows on all succeeding pages?

Answer (score 72):

I know this is an oldish question but I found it whilst looking for the same solution. The solution above doesn't appear to work in Laravel 4, you can however use this now:

```
<a href="{{ URL::previous() }}">Go Back</a>
```

Hope this helps people who look for this feature in L4

(Source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/501/commits)

Answer (score 59):

Laravel 5.2+, back button

```
<a href="{{ url()->previous() }}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 27):

Indeed using `{{ URL:previous() }}` do work, but if you're using a same named route to display multiple views, it will take you back to the first endpoint of this route.

In my case, I have a named route, which based on a parameter selected by the user, can render 3 different views. Of course, I have a default case for the first enter in this route, when the user doesn't selected any option yet.

When I use `URL:previous()`, Laravel take me back to the default view, even if the user has selected some other option. Only using javascript inside the button I accomplished to be returned to the correct view:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()" class="btn btn-default">Voltar</a>
```

I'm tested this on Laravel 5.3, just for clarification.

Comment: thanks its helpful but is there any way to hide this javascript:history.back() url when i hover it in html view.

Comment: @fahdshaykh the only way to do that would be not using an `a` tag for that, and instead use a regular button with this code on n `onClick` method

Comment: It is very useful to save the path back even if the page is refreshed

Comment: @fahdshaykh the only way to hide this would be attaching it to a `onClick` method instead the `href` attribute

Answer (score 17):

The following is a complete Blade (the templating engine Laravel uses) solution:

```
{!! link_to(URL::previous(), 'Cancel', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}
```

The options array with the class is optional, in this case it specifies the styling for a Bootstrap 3 button.

Comment: There is one thing that needs to be changed, instead of {{ ... }} you need to use {!! ... !!} otherwise the string would be escaped.

Comment: True, at the time this worked in Laravel 4 before they were escaped by default. Updated to work with current Laravel versions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

On 5.1 I could only get this to work.

```
<a href="{{ URL::previous() }}" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 4):

You can use javascript for this provblem. 
It's retrieve link from browser history.

```js
<script>
function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

```html
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

Comment: there is a problem with this solution. On the previous page if there is a table (data table), getting the table data is not updated. need the page to reload to update the table. Is there any solution to that issue?

Answer (score 2):

One of the below solve your problem

```
URL::previous() 
URL::back()
```

other

```
URL::current()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="{{ url()->previous() }}" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Continue Shopping</a>
```

This worked in Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 0):

You can use {{ URL::previous() }}
But it not perfect UX.

For example, when you press F5 button and click again to Back Button with {{ URL::previous() }} you will stay in.

A good way is using {{ route('page.edit', $item->id) }} it always true page you wanna to redirect.